# Consuming WCF service in Java does not generate an interface

Tags: java, web-services, wcf

We have a pretty big WCF service that we use for quite some time, but up until now we've been connecting to it only via c#. Now we have a need to connect to it from Java.
I found out quickly that if I use Eclipse and go to new/other/Web Service Client I can put the WSDL link there to auto generate the code.
Doing that straight away did not produce much though. I obtained two files, one of which had empty body. 
This is my first issue with this auto generation tool - it creates something, but I don't see any log of what it succeeded and what failed in creating.
I searched and found out that i had to change the bindings to basicHttpBinding, and make sure that `httpGetEnabled` is set to "`true`". After this change, auto generation in Java produces a lot of code, i get the data contract schemas and so on. And I get 4 files under the '`org.tempuri`' namespace:

```
BasicHttpBinding_IMyServiceStub.java

IMyServiceProxy.java

MyService.java

MyServiceLocator.java
```

However looking at some tutorials, it seems I should get a fifth one, `IMyService.java` - which I did not get. And, I do have errors in the generated code pointing out that indeed IMyService cannot be resolved, as its being used in a few places, but its definition was not auto-generated.
Since I have no logs of what has failed during auto generation, I'm kind of lost what to look for as a culprit.
Does anyone have any experience on either:

> a) locating logs for auto generation that would tell me what went
>   wrong
>   b) directly know what causes the Interface class not to be generated?

I'm suspecting i have to change something more in webconfig file on the server. A second guess is that perhaps we use some c# construct not recognised by java...or something.
Anyway, completly lost here, as there is no feedback of what went wrong.

Here is a webconfig file from the IIS server.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="XXX" connectionString="XXX" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="5400" requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
    <identity impersonate="false"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="bindingNetTcp" closeTimeout="01:00:00" openTimeout="01:00:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00">
          <binaryMessageEncoding maxSessionSize="2147483647">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          </binaryMessageEncoding>
          <tcpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="bindingHttps" closeTimeout="01:00:00" openTimeout="01:00:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00">
          <binaryMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="2147483647" maxWritePoolSize="2147483647" maxSessionSize="2147483647">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          </binaryMessageEncoding>
          <httpsTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" allowCookies="true" authenticationScheme="Anonymous" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="2147483647" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous" realm="" transferMode="StreamedResponse" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false" useDefaultWebProxy="true"/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="bindingHttp" closeTimeout="01:00:00" openTimeout="01:00:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00">
          <binaryMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="2147483647" maxWritePoolSize="2147483647" maxSessionSize="2147483647">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          </binaryMessageEncoding>
          <httpTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" allowCookies="true" authenticationScheme="Anonymous" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="2147483647" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous" realm="" transferMode="StreamedResponse" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false" useDefaultWebProxy="true"/>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IGodService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false"/>
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign"/>
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IGodService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false"/>
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign"/>
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="CustomBinding_IDQMServer">
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="XXX.XXX" behaviorConfiguration="XXXBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://example.com:4502/xxx/xxx/"/>
            <add baseAddress="http://example.com/xxx/xxx/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="bindingHttps" contract="xxx.Ixxx"/>
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="xxx.Ixxx"/>
        <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="bindingNetTcp" contract="xxx.Ixxx"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="xxxBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="2500" maxConcurrentInstances="2147483647" maxConcurrentSessions="2147483647"/>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SrvBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate findValue="xxx" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
            <serviceCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"/>
            </serviceCertificate>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <add value="xxx.svc"/>
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Please note that im using basicHttpBinding there, previously it was "bindingHttp" like the https one, but it didnt work at all.

EDIT: As pointed out in the comment section, we're using Lists in the service quite a lot, an example of the c# wcf interface:

```
public class ListResults<T>//our own custom return class
{
    public List<T> Result { get; set; }

    public long? ID { get; set; }

    public int? Error { get; set; }
}

[SecurityOperationBehavior]
[OperationContract]
ListResults<SomeDataType> SomeListFunction(string param1, long? param2, bool? param3);
```

Comment: Could you share your interface? Which binding are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure which interface you're asking for. I've updated the question with my webconfig file, there are bindings.

Comment: Based in your web.config, you can consume the WCF service using your customBinding, but, for test purpose, add a basicHttpBinding and try to consume the service with this simple binding using your Java client. I asked about the interface because some types in .NET, like List ou Dictionary may have some serialize issues with a Java client.

Comment: It is true, we are using Lists a lot. updating interface example in the main part.

Comment: Those are .net types, but wcf should be able to serialize. Read more about interoperability and conversion here: http://java.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/data-types-interoperability-between-net-and-java

Comment: But try to create a endpoint with basicHttpBinding to test if you can consume your service with a java client.

Comment: Thanks, it's an interesting article, however it doesnt provide an answer to my original question. According to the article I could expect some errors or unexpected behaviour on the data transfered. But my problem seems to be slightly different. In my case automatic tools for generating Java side client code for accessing my WCF service seems to be suffering from some kind of a bug. It simply does not finish generating all the necessary classes (my interface class is missing competently). My undestanding is that it should still generate something even if there are Lists, but it doesnt.

Comment: And I've generated a basicHttpBinding too. If you look at the webconfig, i have this: <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="xxx.Ixxx"/> <- i've added this for testing, and i do get some code generated. just parts seem to be missing.